# primusrun: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

I'm new to linux and I've just installed antergos with gnome de and bumblebee on asus R542 laptop.

When I run `primusrun glxspheres64` it fails and logs this:

```
$ primusrun glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
Visual ID of window: 0x130
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce 930MX/PCIe/SSE2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

`optirun glxspheres64` is ok:

```
$ optirun -c yuv glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
Visual ID of window: 0x21
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce 930MX/PCIe/SSE2
103.963006 frames/sec - 116.022715 Mpixels/sec
104.108801 frames/sec - 116.185422 Mpixels/sec
```

Checked out other forums but non of them could solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the problem is in mesa, xserver or primus, but here's the upstream bug report: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106910 and here's a simple workaround:

```
export LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1
primusrun glxgears
```

Comment: I just uninstalled antergos and replaced it with Manjaro. There is no problem with primusrun but frame rate for `glxgears`  and `optirun glxgears` and `primusrun glxgears` is all at 60 FPS! Any thought on that?

Comment: That'd be vsync I guess.

Comment: And what should I do about that?

Comment: Nothing, you eyes aren't capable of seeing more images per second anyway. :-)